# Setting enumerate item separation in preamble

Tags: formatting, enumerate, preamble

For personal preference, I would like the distance between items inside `enumerate` to be less than the default.

One way to accomplish this is to add `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` to every `enumerate`.
For example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
```

If I wanted to modify the distance between items in my document, I would have to modify *every* `enumerate`.
To avoid this, I added `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` to the preamble of the document.

However, I noticed that this seems to have no effect, as

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
```

and

```
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
```

do not produce the same result; the second `enumerate` produces a list with closer item spacing.

The following is a MWE that illustrates this point:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

So, how would I achieve `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` in the preamble of the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load package `enumitem` and add to your preamble:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0pt}
```

or even

```
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}
```

if you also want no additional spacing w.r.t. the surrounding text: this makes vertical spacings  a little tighter than `[itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt]`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt, topsep = 0pt]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had read about `enumitem` and tried it, but I must have missed the bit about `\setlist`